# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '\node_modules\source-map-support' - npm

Tags: angular, npm, angular7

While Upgrading from Angular 5 to Angular 7, I got few errors like map and forkJoin are deprecated. But those errors are resolved. Still left with one error while running ng serve.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'D:\project\node_modules\source-map-support'
```

Could anyone please help to resolve this error. Not able to figure out which package is dependent on this in the below package.json

**Package.json as follows**

```
{
 "name": "material",
"private": true,
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"hmr": "ng serve --hmr -e=hmr",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e",
"clean": "rimraf node_modules",
"clean-all": "rimraf node_modules dist dll && npm cache clean",
"reinstall": "rimraf node_modules && rm -f package-lock.json && npm install"
},
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^7.2.7",
"@angular/cdk": "^7.3.3",
"@angular/common": "7.2.7",
"@angular/compiler": "7.2.7",
"@angular/core": "7.2.7",
"@angular/forms": "7.2.7",
"@angular/http": "7.2.7",
"@angular/material": "^7.3.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "7.2.7",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.2.7",
"@angular/platform-server": "7.2.7",
"@angular/router": "7.2.7",
"@types/source-map-support": "^0.5.0",
"@types/underscore": "^1.8.13",
"angular-localstorage": "^1.1.5",
"angular2-csv": "^0.2.9",
"angular2-debounce": "^1.0.4",
"angular2-infinite-scroll": "^0.3.5",
"angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^4.2.1",
"angular4-fusioncharts": "^1.0.0",
"bootstrap-scss": "^4.3.1",
"classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
"core-js": "^2.6.5",
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"d3": "^5.9.1",
"easy-pie-chart": "^2.1.7",
"echarts": "^4.1.0",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"fusioncharts": "^3.13.4",
"intl": "^1.2.5",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
"jspdf": "^1.5.3",
"jspdf-autotable": "^3.0.13",
"ng-circle-progress": "^1.4.0",
"ng2-completer": "^2.0.8",
"ng2-dnd": "^5.0.2",
"ng2-smart-table": "^1.4.0",
"ng2-toasty": "^4.0.3",
"ng2modules-easypiechart": "0.0.4",
"ngx-dropdown": "0.0.22",
"ngx-echarts": "^4.1.0",
"ngx-filter-pipe": "^2.1.2",
"ngx-monaco-editor": "^7.0.0",
"ngx-popover": "0.0.16",
"npm": "^6.8.0",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
"rxjs": "^6.4.0",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
"source-map-index-generator": "^0.1.2",
"source-map-support": "^0.4.11",
"underscore": "^1.9.1",
"webfontloader": "^1.6.28",
"zone.js": "^0.8.29"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
"@angular/cli": "^7.3.4",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "7.2.7",
"@angularclass/hmr": "^2.1.3",
"@angularclass/hmr-loader": "^3.0.4",
"@types/core-js": "^2.5.0",
"@types/file-saver": "^2.0.0",
"@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.36",
"@types/jasmine": "^3.3.9",
"@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
"@types/node": "^11.10.4",
"add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.3",
"angular-router-loader": "^0.8.5",
"angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
"autoprefixer": "^9.4.10",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
"bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
"clarity-angular": "^0.10.28",
"codelyzer": "^4.5.0",
"copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0",
"css-loader": "^2.1.0",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
"file-loader": "^3.0.1",
"file-saver": "^2.0.1",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
"jasmine-core": "^3.3.0",
"json-loader": "^0.5.7",
"jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.0",
"karma": "^4.0.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
"karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
"material-design-lite": "^1.3.0",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"ng-router-loader": "^2.1.0",
"node-sass": "^4.11.0",
"postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
"raw-loader": "^1.0.0",
"rimraf": "^2.6.3",
"sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
"style-loader": "^0.23.1",
"ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
"ts-node": "^8.0.2",
"tslib": "^1.9.0",
"tslint": "^5.13.1",
"tslint-loader": "^3.5.4",
"typescript": "^3.2.4",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1",
"webpack-dll-bundles-plugin": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
"webpack-merge": "^4.2.1"
},
"engines": {
"node": ">=6.9.0",
"npm": ">= 3"
}
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It appears as though your `source-map-support` module needs the `path` module to proceed and it can't find said module:

> Can't resolve 'path' in 'D:\project\node_modules\source-map-support'

Perhaps you could try installing this module and see if this resolves your issue:

```
npm install --save path
```

Hopefully that helps!